# Ставлю фон для меню прозрачный но при добавлении на сайт , блок все равно белый

Tags: javascript, html, css, codepen

Подскажите пожалуйста. Через CodePen взял меню, что-бы быстро повесить на сайт со своими корректировками.

Все работает. Кроме бэкграунда. Выставляю его прозрачным но при публикации сайта сзади нижнего меню фон остается белым и перекрывает всю остальную информацию. Буду благодарен.

Ссылка на CodePen: https://codepen.io/uowcladf-the-reactor/pen/OJrbXGV

```
html {

    box-sizing: border-box;
    --bgColorMenu : #1d1d27;
    --duration: .7s;

}

html *,
html *::before,
html *::after {

    box-sizing: inherit;

}

body{
    
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 125, 215, 0.0);
    opacity: 1.0;
    transparent;
    transition: background-color var(--duration);

}

.menu{

    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    /* Works well with 100% width  */
    width: 32.05em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 0 2.85em;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: var(--bgColorMenu);
    
}

.menu__item{
    
    all: unset;
    flex-grow: 1;
    z-index: 100;
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    align-items: center;
    will-change: transform;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0.55em 0 0.85em;
    transition: transform var(--timeOut , var(--duration));
    
}

.menu__item::before{
    
    content: "";
    z-index: -1;
    width: 4.2em;
    height: 4.2em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: background-color var(--duration), transform var(--duration);
    
}


.menu__item.active {

    transform: translate3d(0, -.8em , 0);

}

.menu__item.active::before{
    
    transform: scale(1);
    background-color: #a18c67;

}

.icon{
    
    width: 2.6em;
    height: 2.6em;
    stroke: white;
    fill: transparent;
    stroke-width: 1pt;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
    stroke-dasharray: 400;
    
}

.menu__item.active .icon {

    animation: strok 1.5s reverse;
    
}

@keyframes strok {

    100% {

        stroke-dashoffset: 400;

    }

}

.menu__border{

    left: 0;
    bottom: 99%;
    width: 10.9em;
    height: 2.4em;
    position: absolute;
    clip-path: url(#menu);
    will-change: transform;
    background-color: var(--bgColorMenu);
    transition: transform var(--timeOut , var(--duration));
    
}

.svg-container {

    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 50em) {
    .menu{
        font-size: .8em;
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться, что это такое: `transparent;`?

Comment: @ΝNL993 видимо, это была попытка написать: background-color: transparent; т.е. сделать фон полностью прозрачным. Но, он все равно будет белым

Comment: @Сергей, а есть пример, как Вы хотите чтобы выглядело?

Comment: Я хочу, что-бы сзади мобильного нижнего меню не было никакого фона, так как он перекрывает мне весь контент на сайте. Я не разработчик, балуюсь просто. Есть меню другое, и с ним все в порядке . Здесь же мне нужна именно такая анимация.